# issue combining two mysql queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two queries I am looking to combine into one. This query will be called by backbone in a rails app. The final result should look like this. Thanks in advance.

Title      Impressions    Completed
Test 1234  500            34

```
SELECT title, count(*) as impressions FROM `stats`
WHERE `stats`.`user_id` = 2 
AND (stats.event ='play' and videopos = '0') 
AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY title;

SELECT title, count(*) as completed FROM `stats`
WHERE `stats`.`user_id` = 2 
AND (stats.event ='completed') 
AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY title;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This worked for me.

```
SELECT s.date as date, s.title as title,
  count(F.id) as impressions,
  count(D.event) as completed
FROM stats s
  Left Join stats as F on s.id = F.id and F.event ='play' and F.videopos = '0'
  Left Join stats as D on s.id = D.id and D.event = 'completed'
WHERE s.user_id = '2'
AND (s.date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-18 23:59:59')
AND s.title is not null
GROUP BY s.title
```

Answer (score 1):

try that :

```
  SELECT title,(select count(*)  FROM `stats`  WHERE stats.event ='play' and videopos = '0' AND `stats`.`user_id` = 2 AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') ) as impressions ,(select count(*)  FROM `stats`  WHERE stats.event ='completed' AND `stats`.`user_id` = 2 AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') ) as completed
  FROM `stats`
  WHERE `stats`.`user_id` = 2
  AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') 
  GROUP BY title;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine the result, use `UNION/UNION ALL`

```
SELECT title, count(*) as impressions FROM `stats`
WHERE `stats`.`user_id` = 2 
AND (stats.event ='play' and videopos = '0') 
AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY title

UNION 

SELECT title, count(*) as completed FROM `stats`
WHERE `stats`.`user_id` = 2 
AND (stats.event ='completed') 
AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: I started with the latest query you posted. The trouble is that I was looking to add the completed alias as a column as well. Thanks.

Comment: @jnbankston: In that case, it will be a little more complicated. Let me give some time to the solution

Comment: @jnbankston: I can't find any solution. But see echo_me's solution. It's excellent.

Comment: I tried that solution as well but the impressions and completed numbers are not correct.

Comment: May be the problem is in subquery. Since the subquery don't include other conditions in where clause may be it's counting more than expected. In that case, you may use my solution! Use `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT title, 

Sum(Case When `stats`.`user_id` = 2 
AND (stats.event ='play' and videopos = '0') 
AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59' Then 1 Else 0 End) 
 as impressions , 

Sum(Case When `stats`.`user_id` = 2 
AND (stats.event ='completed') 
AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') Then 1 Else 0 End) 
 as completed

FROM `stats`
WHERE (`stats`.`user_id` = 2 
AND (stats.event ='play' and videopos = '0') 
AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') )
OR
(`stats`.`user_id` = 2 
AND (stats.event ='completed') 
AND (date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-15 23:59:59') )
GROUP BY title;
```

btw, I am coming from ms-sql-server background but I checked on mysql case when syntax. And I typed in notepad, so untested. But I hope you catch the Sum Case When 1 0 idea and tweak it to your requirement..